# raspberry pi access point status

Tags: wifi, pi-4, python-3, terminal, access-point

I have created an access point on my raspberry pi, now I wish write a python program to check if an access point  has been created or not? is it possible to know through command line or python library. If yes, how?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a library function to check if there is an access point created or not. But on the command line you can use `iw` or `wpa_cli`. `iw` is more generic, with `wpa_cli` you have to specify the interface name, but you can get more details if needed.

```
rpi ~$ iw dev | grep 'type AP'
        type AP

# or just check for the return code:
rpi ~$ iw dev | grep --quiet 'type AP'
rpi ~$ echo $?
0

rpi ~$ wpa_cli -iwlan0 status | grep 'mode=AP'
mode=AP

# or just check for the return code:
rpi ~$ wpa_cli -iwlan0 status | grep --quiet 'mode=AP'
rpi ~$ echo $?
0
```